# Merge Or Create Table And Swap?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake that I merge changes into often (1-2 times per day). Row updates are streamed into an updates table and I query the updates table as will as the primary table at the same time. When I do merge the updates into the primary table, I use the the MERGE command:

```
MERGE INTO primary p
        USING (
            SELECT ... FROM (
               SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY last_updated_at DESC) rn FROM updates
            ) WHERE rn = 1
        ) se
        ON (p.id = u.id)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET ...
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (...)
            VALUES (...)
```

The number of updates and the size of the table means that my primary table is entirely rewritten when this happens. While not ideal, this alone is not an issue for us because we don't do it often and when we do we use a large enough warehouse to complete the merge in under 10m.

My question is, since the table gets rebuilt anyway, is there a reason not to merge results into an entirely new table where the results can be pre-clustered (order by cluster columns) and then swap the tables? Is merge doing anything more efficiently here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of ORDER BY on the UPDATE/MERGE commands, is a blessing if you want raw performance, of the UPDATE/MERGE.

But if as you note, if you are using clustering, then after the update/merge you might have hours of poor SELECT performance, and pay a lot more of the privilege of the auto-clustering on the table.  We experienced a 2x+ cost of the auto clustering as compared to a full rewrite for a table for an update to a table where 1/3 of the partitions where re-written. The is just the computer costs of the full table write verse the auto clustering credit uses, over the couple hours after the update. I didn't track what the increase in disk usage was because of the churn, but normally considered space free in comparison to compute credits.

Comment: That makes sense. So because I do want clustering, and the full table gets rewritten anyway, would you recommend just doing a full table rewrite with an ORDER BY then

Comment: Yes, as a starting point. This advice might change at some point, as I was told a change was in development to "try respect prior clustering on UPDATEs" which would imply also MERGE's. But I have not seen that announced.

Comment: As a note - you mention using a CTAS and then SWAP as your method of rebuilding the table.  I highly recommend that you instead leverage the INSERT WITH OVERWRITE statement, which will directly overwrite the table, you can include an ORDER BY, and you will maintain your time-travel.  And it is essentially the same thing as a CTAS.